# IWebBrower2.Navigate Not Rendering Checkboxes when ran as a Windows Service

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, checkbox, iwebbrowser2

I have a class I scraped together called HtmlPrinter which contains a method called 'Print' that takes in a html file, renders using IWebBrowser2.Navigate, then prints using IWebBrowser2.ExecWB.  My HtmlPrinter.Print method works great and renders the HTML as expected EXCEPT when the code is run in the context of a Windows Service.  When running as a Windows Service text appears scrunched and most notably the checkbox for checkbox inputs does not render.

Here is the very simple code of an HTML file I am testing with:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" checked/>This should be checked but is not when printing from Windows Service
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the HtmlPrinter class which you can call using HtmlPrinter.Print("\Path\sample.html", "NameOfPrinter")

```
/// <summary>
/// Manges the Printing of HTML documents using the InternetExplorer object
/// Requires reference to COM "Microsoft Internet Controls"
/// Code derived from stackoverflow.com post #2561078
/// </summary>
public static class HtmlPrinter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the Default Printer in Windows
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="printerName">Name of the Printer</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string printerName);

    private static bool docLoaded;
    private static bool docPrinted;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the docLoaded attribute to true once DocumentCompleteEventHandler executes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pDisp">Object that specifies the top-level or frame WebBrowser object corresponding to the event</param>
    /// <param name="URL">String that specifies the URL, Universal Naming Convention (UNC) file name, or pointer to an item identifier list (PIDL) of the loaded document</param>
    private static void ie_DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        docLoaded = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the docPrinted attribute to true once PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler executes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pDisp">Object that evaluates to the top-level or frame WebBrowser object corresponding to the navigation.</param>
    private static void ie_PrintTemplateTeardown(object pDisp)
    {
        docPrinted = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load the HTML document and print the document to the specified printer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlFilename">Full Path to the HTML file</param>
    /// <param name="printerName">Name of printer ot print to</param>
    public static void Print(string htmlFilename, string printerName)
    {
        docLoaded = false;
        docPrinted = false;

        //store the current default printer so we can revert it back later if necessary
        string defPrinter = GetDefaultPrinter();

        //modify the default printer if it's not already set to the preferred printer
        if (printerName != defPrinter)
        {
            SetDefaultPrinter(printerName);
        }

        InternetExplorer ie = new InternetExplorer();
        ie.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(ie_DocumentComplete);
        ie.PrintTemplateTeardown += new DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler(ie_PrintTemplateTeardown);

        object missing = Missing.Value;

        //load the document then enter waiting loop until the DocumentComplete event is called
        ie.Navigate(htmlFilename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        while (!docLoaded && ie.QueryStatusWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT) != OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        //start printing with no user interaction using ExecWB then wait until the PrintTemplateTeardown
        //event which fires once the print template is destroyedr
        ie.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, ref missing, ref missing);
        while (!docPrinted)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        ie.DocumentComplete -= ie_DocumentComplete;
        ie.PrintTemplateTeardown -= ie_PrintTemplateTeardown;
        ie.Quit();

        //if original default printer was different than preferred printer, revert back to origianl default
        if (printerName != defPrinter)
        {
            SetDefaultPrinter(defPrinter);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name the Default Printer configured in Windows
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Name of the default printer</returns>
    private static string GetDefaultPrinter()
    {
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();

        string defPrinter = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>().Where(x =>
        {
            ps.PrinterName = x;
            return (ps.IsDefaultPrinter == true);
        }).FirstOrDefault();

        //if no default printer found, set to first printer in collection
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(defPrinter))
        {
            defPrinter = ps.PrinterName;
        }

        //if still not print found, set to hardcoded text
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(defPrinter))
        {
            defPrinter = "NO DEFAULT PRINTER SET";
        }

        return defPrinter;
    }
}
```

Again, when I call HtmlPrinter.Print from a standard console application, the checkbox renders correctly.  However, when calling the Print method from within a Windows Service, the check does not render as in the screenshot below.  What is it about a Windows Service context that prevents the checkbox from rendering?  Things I have tried:

- Ensured Windows Service is being run as the same user in which I ran my console application.  So, it's not an issue with the logged in user
- Tried adding different !DocType tags to the HTML Head
- Added localhost to IE Trusted Sites
- Disabled IE Protected Mode
- Confirmed issue happens on multiple workstations (tested Windows 7 32-bit with IE 11 and Windows Server 2008 64-bit with IE 10)

[image: WindowsServicePrintSample]

Comment: Hate to be the bearer of bad news, but I'll bet this is just the first of many (MANY) issues you'll encounter when trying to use IE from a Windows Service.

Comment: Can you elaborate, Michael?  What causes IE from a Windows Service to act so much differently than when not run as a service?  Is a different rendering engine used?

Comment: Windows Services are supposed to be UI-less. The entire architecture assumes that. The only accepted form of UI feedback from a service is a [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) with the `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION` flag. IE, however, is very dependent upon the display surface for its rendering.

Comment: Actually, there are some other acceptable interactions with the desktop, but I don't think you're going to get what you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502.aspx

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not sure how this applies necessarily since the InternetExplorer and IWebBrowswer2 objects themselves aren't invoking any UI so the service has no need to interact with the desktop.  They are rendering in memory and the same code works from a console application (which also doesn't invoke any UI).  If this code required any sort of UI then it would fail altogether.  As it is, the code works fine but I'm just trying to figure out why the checkboxes aren't rendering.

Comment: A lot of UIs expect certain Windows messages to initialize themselves properly. A common example in .NET is code running in the Load event handler of, say, a Window or Form. When you remove the physical (or virtual) display from the equation, Windows may communicate with the window differently. For example, the window may never get, say, the WM_MOVE or WM_SIZE messages which many developers use to lay out the child controls/windows/UIElements on screen. I'd be willing to bet your failure-to-check error is something like this.

Comment: Okay I understand, thanks.  I'll leave this open though to see if any one has a workaround or even a completely different way to render and print HTML altogether.